# Is it necessary to specify which element is above another element in a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

Imagine I have the following elements in a ConstraintLayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/blue" 
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As a result it is only shown the black view (view2) because it is above (graphically, not in the xml) the blue view(view1)

Now my question is, do I need to specify which element is above another element with some attribute or it is already specified by putting one element below another in the xml?

I mean I have seen that if element 1 is below element 2 in the xml file, then, element 1 is actually above element 2 although element 1 is below element 2 in the xml file and that is a little confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create a function that gives us to child views of the given view, paste below code to your fragment:

```
    private fun View.getAllChildren(): List<View> {
        val result = ArrayList<View>()
        if (this !is ViewGroup) {
            result.add(this)
        } else {
            for (index in 0 until this.childCount) {
                val child = this.getChildAt(index)
                result.addAll(child.getAllChildren())
            }
        }
        return result
    }
```

Now give our `ConstraintLayout` an id:

```
    android:id="@+id/cl_parent"
```

And use our function on this parent to get it's children. Then loop through it and paste view names into `Log` You can paste below to your `onViewCreated` or elsewhere:
If you want to use elevations, just add something like `android:elevation="1dp"` to your first view and `android:elevation="2dp"` for your second view in xml file:

```
        for (childView in cl_parent.getAllChildren()) {
            val fullName = resources.getResourceName(childView.id)
            val elevationValue = childView.elevation.toString()
            Log.e("childView", "$fullName $elevationValue")
        }
```

This will give you view names and elevations of them. The higher value will be on top and visible to user. In your case:
Output:

```
:id/view1 2.75
:id/view2 5.5
```

Comment: In that code all the space is dividied by 2 so that one half of the layout is occupied by View 1 and the other half by View 2.  I didn't want that, what I wanted is to know if there was an atribbute to determine which View is at the "Front" and what view is at the "Back" . To let you understand is like the layers in photograph edition programs like Photoshop, I was wondering if there was a possibility to make layers so that one View is in Layer 1 and another is in Layer 2 to determine which one is under the other. Althoug hanks for your awnser :)

Comment: I think now i understand your question, check edited answer.

Comment: I have seen an attribute that is called android:elevation, is that attribute neccesary to determine which element is above the other in the z axis?

Comment: Yes higher elevation will be on top. Previous answer was for without elevations, now it will get elevations too.

Comment: And if I have a ConstraintLyout with two children: first child is view 1 and second child is view 2, so automatically view 2 will be on top. In this example although I have already the result I want, do I need to specify for example elevation of view 1: 1dp and elevation of view 2: 2dp or it is unnecessary because if element 1 is under element 2 in the xml file, the element 2 will be always on top although I have not specified the elevation attribute?

Comment: If you do not add `elevation` to xml then it will work as intended, i mean the below element on xml will be on top. But for example if you have 3 views inside one `ConstraintLayout` and first one's elevation is 1, second one's elevation is 3 and third one's elevation is 2. So in this condition, second view will be on top, because you are changing it's elevation on purpose.

Comment: Nice glad to help, please mark this answer as accepted for closure of question.